# Installing Windows 8 Preview on a Mac?

Tags: windows, bootcamp, vmware

I'm just wondering if anyone has figured this out yet. VMWare throws an ugly "internal monitor error" and there are apparently some graphics driver issues on the 2011 Macbook Pros.

Comment: This is working fine for me on Parallels 6 installed straight out of the ISO configured with the Parallels Windows 7 profile. On 10.6.8, Late 09 MacBook (NVidia 9400M).

Comment: Questions about prerelease software are off-topic for this site. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Comment: @Nathan Greenstein, I was about to flag it, but I noticed that the FAQ says that "pre-release or beta software requiring a non-disclosure agreement (NDA) to use" is off-topic. If you go to Microsoft's site at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/br229516, you can download the developer preview *without consenting to any NDA*. Doesn't that mean it doesn't violate the rule?

Comment: That is a valid point. See my [answer](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/798/pre-release-software-that-doesnt-require-an-nda/799#799) to the meta post.

Answer (score 2):

Just my luck, VMWare Fusion 4 came out today and I was able to install Windows 8 on that. Boot Camp still has the graphics driver issues, but that's probably not going to resolve itself until Apple gets around to doing an update.

The latest Virtual Box also installs Windows 8 with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running it in [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/)? I haven't tested this but I had this working with the first beta of Windows 7 back in 2008 and that worked first time! Well, the install did ;)

Comment: VirtualBox has some issues with Win8 and it's very very slow

Comment: Ah ok. You can't really blame them as it's only a developer preview ;) Thanks for the info.